# Не работают листенеры после обновления Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view-binding

Всем привет!
Возобновил работу над старым проектом, работавшим в версии Android Studio 21-го года (Bumblebee). После обновления до текущей версии (Giraffe) обнаружилось, что некоторые листенеры не срабатывают. Особенность несрабатывающих листенеров в том, что разметка, на к-рой находятся кликаемые View, подключается в главную разметку через include.
Текст проекта великоват, приведу самые значимые моменты:

Главная разметка, файл power_unit_fragment.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
....
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/powerunit_ControlFrame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/powerunit_infoFrame"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/powerunit_infoFrame">

        <include layout="@layout/powerunit_control" />
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Разметка с кликаемыми элементами, файл powerunit_control.xml:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/emStop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/green_red_button_color"
                android:text="E.Stop on"
                />
</LinearLayout>
```

В onCreateView фрагмента, где используется биндинг и листенеры:

```
       powerUnitFragmentBinding = PowerUnitFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false) //биндинг "главного" окна
       powerunitControlBinding = PowerunitControlBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)  // биндинг подключенного includ-ом окошка с кнопкой

//листенер кнопки
        powerunitControlBinding.emStop.setOnClickListener {
....
        }
//onCreateView завершается возвратом 
        return powerUnitFragmentBinding.root  //что вроде бы правильно
```

Так вот, листенер устанавливается, но не срабатывает никогда. Что можно предположить?

Comment: Android Studio тут точно ни при чем, это среда разработки, не исполнения. Смотрите что изменилось именно в проекте.

Comment: Не срабатывают ГДЕ? В эмуляторе? На телефоне? Сейчас вопрос выглядит как "я обновил мс оффис и у меня перестал работать интернет".

Comment: Не срабатывают нигде, ни в эмуляторе, ни в "живом" устройстве. 
Проект не менялся кроме изменений системы сборки, сопутствующих апгрейду версии AS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, верно подозревал, что причина была в подключении разметки. Все заработало после нижеописанных изменений.
При подключении разметки через include добавил идентификатор подключаемого файла:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/powerunit_ControlFrame"
    layout="@layout/powerunit_control" />
```

Биндинг:

```
binding = PowerUnitFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false) //биндинг "корневой" разметки
powerunitControlBinding = binding.powerunitControlFrame //используется добавленный id
```

Листенер остался без изменений.
В общем, есть какой-то нюанс во взаимоотношениях view binding и составной разметки.

Comment: Биндинг не обрабатывает теги без `id`. В варианте из вопроса вы "надули" отдельно вторую разметку, не связанную с первой и получается навесили колбеки на дубликаты кнопок в памяти, а не на те что вывели на экран вместе с первой разметкой

Comment: Да, похоже на правду, спасибо!
Немного сбивает с толку, что в ранее установленной Android Studio вариант из вопроса работал нормально, так как если бы include работало в C-подобной манере, т.е. включало текст файла и id кнопок виделись как находящиеся в "корневой" разметке.